# Can't upload format files on media library

Tags: customization, uploads, media, media-library, media-settings

I have an issue for uploading .ppsx format on the media library. all the powerpoint format (pptx ppt, pps) can be uploading without problem except the .ppsx format and i don't know why.

when i try to upload this format i have this message :
**Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons.**

Even though WordPress by default(wp_get_mime_types()) allow .ppsx, I try the following methods, but method 1 and 2 does not work and method 3 is not secure and does not work for no admin users.

**First Method:**

Add the file type through my theme functions.php (Microsoft MIME Type Confirmed Here):

```
function allow_file_types($mime_types){
    $mime_types['ppsx'] = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow';
    return $mime_types;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'allow_file_types', 1, 1);
```

**Second Method:**
Install plugins, which is does the exact same thing as my functions.php method.

WP Extra File Types
WP Add Mime Types

**Third Method:**
Add this line of code on the wp-config.php

```
define(‘ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS’, true)
```

this method is not secure for me and only admin can upload the .ppsx files)

**method that partially works (method 4)**

The only method that partially works is to add the below code :

```
function my_check_filetype_and_ext( $info, $file, $filename, $mimes, $real_mime )
{
    if ( empty( $check['ext'] ) && empty( $check['type'] ) )
    {
        $secondaryMimetypes = ['ppsx' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation'];

        // Run another check, but only for our secondary mime and not on core mime types.
        remove_filter( 'wp_check_filetype_and_ext', 'my_check_filetype_and_ext', 99, 5 );
        $info = wp_check_filetype_and_ext( $file, $filename, $secondaryMimetypes );
        add_filter( 'wp_check_filetype_and_ext', 'my_check_filetype_and_ext', 99, 5 );
    }

    return $info;
}
add_filter( 'wp_check_filetype_and_ext', 'my_check_filetype_and_ext', 99, 5 );
```

The problem is if we add this code on functions.php we will be able to upload .ppsx files but all others format can't be uploaded in media library.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: which version of WordPress are you using? WP already has ppsx support built in, it was already in WP at least 8 years ago. Your issue is more likely to be that PPSX support is being removed by broken/faulty code, not that it needs adding. Disable all plugins, switch to the default theme, and try again, then re-activate plugins until PPSX uploads stop working

Comment: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/9115246f7292b8ead3b0cca45a5fa604f2d45706/wp-includes/functions.php#L3168 for reference

Comment: PPSX support was introduced 10 years ago by Otto in https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/commit/94dd7f757b5a73533c808106b2b089e4556464ae, which was WordPress v3.1, here's the ticket that added PPSX support https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17117 which discusses Office 2007 support

Comment: Could it be that ppsx was deleted from the list of allowed formats in the network admin media settings?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tom. I'm using wordpress 5.5.3 (last version). I don't delete .ppsx from the list of allowed formats. have this problem of uploading in 2 servers. for tests purpose i added a fresh WordPress installation without any additionnel plugins and still have the same issue.

Comment: The filter my_check_filetype_and_ext looks wrong - what is the variable $check referencing - should that be $file ?

Comment: Thanks for your replay Q studio, if the code is wrong. is it possible to send me a reply with the right code please. I found it on an article

Comment: I reproduced this in a vanilla WP install, you should not need extra code to do this, it should work out of the box. You need to report this as a bug on the official WP Trac bug tracker at https://core.trac.wordpress.org/

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the bug being reported, you might have some mileage trying the following in your `wp-config.php` file:

```
define( 'ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true );
```

If you’d prefer not to edit your `wp-config.php` file and/or you want more control over exactly which file types can be uploaded to your site, you can use the free [WP Extra File Types](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-extra-file-types/) plugin at WordPress.org